# Is my logic correct? A bit string of n with more 0s than 1s

Tags: string, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, discrete

[image]

I am learning about combinatorial and bit strings. I want to solve for a string with unknown length but has 0s than 1s.

I decided to use combinatorial reasoning and explain my thinking

Is my logic and formula correct? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe try [math.se]?

Comment: This should be correct, but you could write it more easily: if you think about it, the amount of numbers where there are more 0s than 1s is equal to the amount of numbers where there are more 1s than 0s. Therefore, you could compute the number of such numbers as the amount of strings minus the amount of strings containing equal amount of 0s and 1s, equalling (2^n - n_over_n/2) / 2 for even string length, and 2^(n-1) for odd n